# how to add a list to a class in python?

Tags: python-2.7, oop

I'm trying to autogenerate enemies for a game in python. These enemies have a large number of attributes and those will change according to development.

I'm failing to add these skills in a useful way to a class.

```
combatskills = ["sword", "spear", "axe"]

class Enemy(object):
    def __init__(self):
        for x in combatskills:
            self.x = 0

orc1 = Enemy()
```

The purpoted goal is to end up with being able to call orc1.sword, but I don't know how to dynamically create Enemy.[combatskills] attributes.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I was looking for setattr

```
class Enemy(object):
    def __init__(self):
        for x in combatskills:
            setattr(self, x, 0)
```

Solved what I was trying to do.